# jQuery validation border color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex, validation

I have written a piece of code to validate some text field but it is not quite working as I need it to.

I check each field for a valid input in two ways, once for a valid email address (using regex) and once to check if the field is empty. Then I display any error messages and change the border colour of the related text boxes.

The problem I am facing comes when I want to reset the border color if there were no issues in the validation process but I think the way I have set up my code is making it difficult for me to achieve this.

```
function validation() {
    var errorList = '';

    validate_email("input[id$='tbTheirEmail']", "Sorry, the recipient’s email address is invalid.");
    validate_email("input[id$='tbYourEmail']", "Sorry, your email address is invalid.");

    validate_field("input[id$='tbTheirEmail']", 'Sorry, you need to enter a recipient’s email address.');
    validate_field("input[id$='tbYourEmail']", 'Sorry, you need provide your email address.');

    if (errorList <= 0) {
        SendEmail();
        $("#popupErrorMessage ul").html('');

    }
    else {
        $("#popupErrorMessage ul").html(errorList);
    }

    function validate_email(email, message) {
        var regex = (/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/i);
        if ($(email).val() != '') {
            if (!regex.test($(email).val())) {
                errorList += "<li>" + message + "</li>";
                $(email).css("border-color", "#da1f27");
            }
            else{
                $(email).css("border-color", "#e6e7e8");
            }
        }
    }
    function validate_field(element, message) {
    if ($(element).val() == '') {
        errorList += "<li>" + message + "</li>";
        $(element).css("border-color", "#da1f27");
    }
    else{
       $(element).css("border-color", "#e6e7e8");
    }
}
}
```

You may notice in the code that the validation check is performed followed by the empty field check. So if the valid email function fails, the error is displayed and the border changes but then the empty field function fires and passes straight away so the color is immediately changed back to the old color which is not what I want.

I suspect that my function will need to be restructured to achieve this but I am unsure how to go about it so any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would recommend using a class to change the textfield borders instead of simply changing CSS. What you need to do is setup two new classes on your CSS. For example:

```
.validBorder {
    border-color: #e6e7e8;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style: solid;
}

.invalidBorder {
    border-color: #da1f27;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Then instead of calling `$(element).css("border-color", "#da1f27");` just call `$(element).addClass('validBorder');` or `invalidBorder` depending on the case.

Hope this helps you!